# Custom Event throws TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am trying to create a TypeScript Component in React and want to add a custom Drag Start Event. I have the following Code right now:

```
import React, {RefObject, useEffect, useState} from "react";

type Props = {
    id: string,
    effect: DataTransfer["dropEffect"],
    ref: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    onDragStart: any
}

export default function useDrag({id, effect, ref, onDragStart}: Props) {
    const [dragState, updateDragState] = useState<string>("draggable");

    const dragStart = (event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>): any => {
        updateDragState("dragStart");
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = effect;
        event.dataTransfer.setData("source", id);
         onDragStart && onDragStart()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const element = ref.current;

        if (element) {
            element.setAttribute("draggable", String(true));
            element.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);

            return () => {
                element.removeEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
            }

        }

    })

}
```

But I am always getting the following Error when trying to add the custom Event:

TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "dragstart", listener: (this: HTMLDivElement, ev: DragEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(event: React.DragEvent) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLDivElement, ev: DragEvent) => any'.       Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.         Type 'DragEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'DragEvent': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist   Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(event: React.DragEvent) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.       Type '(event: React.DragEvent) => any' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.         Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.           Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'DragEvent': dataTransfer, altKey, button, buttons, and 19 more.

Answer (score 0):

React uses [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) for callbacks so type of `React.DragEvent` is not equal to the type `addEventListener` is expecting. Moreover you should not be registering event callbacks with a ref and useEffect, you can implement the drag feature with

```html
<div draggable="true" onDragStart={handleDragStart} />
```

Comment: Ok, but i would like to create it as a Hook so i can use add it to the Components i want.

Comment: Why a hook? Why not a custom component?

Comment: I think i can also create a custom Component. I found an article where it says how to create a custom hool.